# How to edit user profile in django rest framework from two models and save the change

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-2.0

I am trying to create an endpoint to edit both the user model and custom profile model below.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile')
```

In the regular django I would do:

**views.py**

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST,
                                            request.FILES,
                                            instance=request.user.profile)        
        if form.is_valid() and extended_profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            extended_profile_form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:profile')
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
            'form':form,
            'extended_profile_form':extended_profile_form
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/edit-profile.html', context)
```

what is the equivalent for django rest framework?

I have tried:

**views.py** **(Django Rest Framework)**

```
@api_view(['GET','PUT'])
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user  = User.objects.filter(username=request.user)
        profile_user = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        serializer_user = UserSerializer(user, many=True)
        serializer_profile_user = ProfileSerializer(profile_user, many=True)
        result = {'serializer_user': serializer_user.data, 'serializer_profile_user': serializer_profile_user.data}
        return Response(result)
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        user  = User.objects.filter(username=request.user)
        profile_user = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        serializer_user = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        serializer_profile_user = ProfileSerializer(profile_user, data=request.data)
        if serializer_user.is_valid() and serializer_profile_user.is_valid():
            serializer_user.save()
            serializer_profile_user.save()
            result = {'serializer_user': serializer_user.data, 'serializer_profile_user': serializer_profile_user.data}
            return Response(result)
        result = {'serializer_user': serializer_user.data, 'serializer_profile_user': serializer_profile_user.data}
        return Response(result.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I am browsing the endpoint, it does display `serializer_user` and `serializer_profile_user` data but I am unable to edit any of those data using the DRF browsable API.

Am I right thinking the codes above is the equivalent of the codes from the codes from the normal django to edit the profile of the user?

Comment: @engin_ipek it does thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine to me, but you need to replace this:

```
 if request.method == 'GET':
    user  = User.objects.filter(username=request.user)
```

with this:

```
 if request.method == 'GET':
    try:
        user  = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
         return Response(data='no such user!', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    # you need to use objects.get because objects.filter returns a queryset not an abject
```

Because, request.user is an instance of User model, you cannot compare it to an attribute of user (in your case username)

PS: same goes with your PUT method as well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Look. You can make it easier. Let's take Post model (for example):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(base.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(base.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

And that You should describe it in your serializer (serializer is something similar to DTO. It converts data into a service-friendly JSON view):

```
class PostCreateUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'text']
```

And the last part - Endpoint:

```
class PostUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostCreateUpdateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```

It will be more comfortable to use CBV for [Django](http://ccbv.co.uk/) and [DRF](http://www.cdrf.co/)

And One more thing. You shouldn't create one more table for your user model. This is due to the extension of the BaseUser model. [Link for help](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Could you add the solution for function based view as well? I will use both for future references. Thanks